# template function parameters conversion

Tags: c++

Given the following simple (and stupid :) ) class template:

```
template<typename T>
class Temp {

int _a;
int _b;
int _c;

public:
template<typename F>
Temp(F a, F b, F c) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {}

template<>
Temp(const string& a, const string& b, const string& c) : _a(1), _b(2), _c(3) {}
};
```

There's a main ctor and a ctor speciailization for strings.
I know the class doesn't make any sense but that is not the point.

When I try to do:

```
Temp<int> t1("a", "b", "c");
```

It won't let me.

But If I change :

```
Temp(const string& a, const string& b, const string& c) : _a(1), _b(2), _c(3) {}
```

to:

```
Temp(const char* a, const char* b, const char* c) : _a1(),_b(2),_c(3) {}
```

It does let me do it.

Shouldn't the compiler accept a string literal for a string object?
I mean, they did (I suppose) defined a ctor which accept a const char *..
and since things like:

```
void foo(const string& s) {}
```

and

```
foo("Hey there");
```

Work, I guess it has something to do with templates arguments.

Would love to get a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

- **Shouldn't the compiler accept a string literal for a string object?**

Only if it's unambiguous. In your case, `Temp<int> t1("a", "b", "c");` has two possibilities:

- `template<typename F> Temp(F a, F b, F c)` with `F=const char[2]`
- `template<> Temp(const string& a, const string& b, const string& c)`

As far as the compiler is concerned both are valid, but the first one matches exactly, so it will be chosen.

If you do the conversion yourself then you disambiguate that choice:

```
Temp<int> t1(string("a"), string("b"), string("c"));
```

Note: If you find yourself typing a phrase like "It won't let me" it should be directly followed by a copy/paste of the actual error you're getting.

Comment: It has nothing to do with templates arguments? so how does it allow the 'auto' conversion in the 2nd example?

Comment: @Rouki you mean for this function: `Temp(const char* a, ...`)? String literals are already `const char*`.

Comment: No, the simple FOO function

Comment: @Rouki Yes, you're right. It's likely that that it is templates, where that first generic constructor makes your call ambiguous. See my edit.

Comment: Oh, so its all about ambigiuity then :D?

Comment: Actually when I tried it with plain template functions it's not ambiguous at all, the first constructor is taken with no errors. I.e. the one you seem to not want. Hence my edited note about compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

A uick answer would be, most of implicit type conversions are not done/ are restricted 
 in templated functions.